# How can I fix `Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code.`?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using redux forms in react project and this is the app component which has redux forms intialized :

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const onSubmit = (values) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
};
function App(props) {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            {props.number}
            <button onClick={() => props.callAction()} />
        </div>
    );
}


App = reduxForm({
    form: 'contact',
    onSubmit
})(App);
```

But I get this error in the console which is coming from react strict mode :

```
 Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code.
* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at:state

Please update the following components: Field, Form(App)
```

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) commented, there seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/3954) about this. I should either wait for the authors of redux-form to release an update or seek an alternative library (because the author of this one seems to say that we shouldn't be using it in most cases).

Answer (score 39):

In my case, I believe the issue was due to Helmet from `"react-helmet"`

to fix the issue I used `react-helmet-async` and wrap everything in `<HelmetProvider>` under jsx return

below is a sample code

**code with issue**

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

function XYZ(){
return(
 <div>
   <Helmet>
     <meta />
   </Helmet>
 
   <p>...</p>
 </div>
)
}
```

**code with fix**

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';


function XYZ(){
return(
<HelmetProvider>
  <div>
    <Helmet>
      <meta />
    </Helmet>
 
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</HelmetProvider>

)
}
```

Comment: This does solve the problem, though the license changes from MIT for react-helmet to Apache 2.0 for react-helmet-async. For my use-case I just needed to set the title; I ended up using useEffect and setting document.title in it.

Comment: COMMENT OUT YOUR HELMET CODE - will prove if this is the problem for you, it is for me.

Comment: Same here! I had multiple files with the Helmet code, I had to wrap my returns with HelmetProvider, and only then this error got removed.

Comment: Awesome, Do you know the root of it?

Answer (score 3):

in my case helmet was the issue
so to resolve

npm install react-helmet-async

and

`import React from "react";

import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';

```
<HelmetProvider>
    <Helmet>
      <title>{`${title} - ShopIT`}</title>
    </Helmet>
</HelmetProvider>
```